# Retrofit Service methods cannot return void

Tags: android, retrofit2

I have below method in my Api Interface.I am trying to post and return data from the same page

```
   public interface ApiInterface {

   @FormUrlEncoded // annotation used in POST type requests

   @POST("/pagee1.php")     // API's endpoints

   public void registration(@Field("param1") String param1,
                         @Field("param2") String param2,
                         @Field("param3") String param3,
                         @Field("param4") String param4,
                         @Field("param5") String param5,
                         Callback<UserListResponse> callback);

@GET("/pagee1.php")
public void getUsersList
Callback<List<UserListResponse>> callback);
```

}

And this is my post_Data method using above ApiInterface registration

```
 private void Post_Data() {

    Api.getClient().registration("value1", "value2", "value3", "value4", "value5", new Callback<UserListResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<UserListResponse> call, retrofit2.Response<UserListResponse> response) {
            progressDialog.dismiss(); //dismiss progress dialog
            getUserListData();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<UserListResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), t.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.e("Retrofit_callback Error", t.toString());

        }
    });

}
```

But it is giving Error on `Api.getClient().registration` position and below is the error code

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service methods cannot return void.
    for method ApiInterface.getUsersList
```

what's wrong I am doing

Answer (score 1):

You need to change to this :

```java
public interface ApiInterface {

    @FormUrlEncoded // annotation used in POST type requests
    @POST("/pagee1.php")     // API's endpoints
    public Call<UserListResponse> registration(@Field("param1") String param1,
                         @Field("param2") String param2,
                             @Field("param3") String param3,
                             @Field("param4") String param4,
                             @Field("param5") String param5);

    @GET("/pagee1.php")
    public Call<List<UserListResponse>> getUsersList();

}
```

Your calls a returning something which is `Call<YourEntity>`. Have a look at this [tutorial](https://www.journaldev.com/13639/retrofit-android-example-tutorial) for a better understanding of Retrofit.

Comment: Now I am having a required java.utlil.list in calling getUsersList() `List<UserListResponse> userListResponseData;                 
                                     Call<UserListResponse> call2 = Api.getClient().getUsersList();
        call2.enqueue(new Callback<UserListResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<UserListResponse> call, retrofit2.Response<UserListResponse> response) {
                progressDialog.dismiss(); 
                userListResponseData=response.body();// here showing the error
                setDataInRecyclerView()
    }`

Comment: Can you instead add this code in your initial post for a better readability and add the logcat error if you have one